# Replacing string in UTF-16LE encoded file

Tags: ruby, regex, encoding, utf-16

I have an auto-generated file that is encoded in UTF-16LE and I want to write a Ruby script that searches for a version number via a regular expression and replaces it with a new version number. Here is what I initially was trying to use:

```
File.open(filepath,"rb:UTF-16") do |file|
  file.each do |line|
    line.gsub!(/FILEVERSION \d\.\d/,FILEVERSION)
  end
end
```

This however did not work as I was getting an error message that said "incompatible encoding regexp match(US-ASCII regexp with UTF-16 string)". I tried to force encode my FILEVERSION string in UTF-16 but got the same error. One of my coworkers said that you can't effectively use regexes in UTF-16 encoding. Is there a workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work if you're careful to encode everything in UTF-16LE.

```
re = Regexp.new('FILEVERSION \d\.\d'.encode('UTF-16LE'))
File.open(filepath,"rb:UTF-16LE") do |file|
    file.each do |line|
        line.gsub!(re, FILEVERSION.encode('UTF-16LE'))
    end
end
```

Comment: I don't get errors anymore but it isn't changing anything in the file. Not sure what's wrong, the file isn't read-only

Comment: You still need to write modified lines back somewhere, of course. That won't happen automatically. I thought this question was just about the encoding problem.

Comment: Ahh ok. I forgot that I opened the file for reading. Thanks!